# Google Form API - Error when Create new item in form

Tags: forms

I am getting this error while create new item in google form using google form api. Please let me know, what goes wrong in this code. Thank you in advance.

"error" : {
"message" : "Invalid requests[0]: create_item.location.index is invalid or was not provided",
"status" : "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
"code" : 400
}

Here is my code snippet
let url = "https://forms.googleapis.com/v1/forms/formId:batchUpdate?access_token=(token)"

let parameters: [String: Any] = ["requests" : [ "createItem": ["item" : ["title": "Update Form Data"], "location" : ["index" : 1]] as [String : Any]]]

AF.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseData(completionHandler: { response in
guard let data = response.data else { return }
let json = try? JSON(data:data)
print(json as Any)
})